# Arduino Mega vs Uno

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, multiplexing, eeprom, flash-memory

We're programming a doorbell recognition system and have decided to use the Arduino to handle most of the circuitry. The one thing I'm unsure of is the program capacity of the [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) vs the [Arduino Mega](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega). I know the Uno has only about 32 KB of flash memory, but our program is projected to land within a thousand lines of code (which I assume would go over the 32 KB threshold).

We don't have much time to complete the project, so we don't want to spend a lot of time figuring out how to multiplex or add memory to the Uno if it can't handle what we need from it out of the box.

How difficult (and time consuming) would it be to add [EEPROMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EEPROM) to the Uno? Would it be better to just stick with the Mega?

Also, would it be easier to just use a PC (with a DAQ board or something else) or a [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) rather than an Arduino in the first place?

The system we are designing is being used to read input from a fingerprint scanner and output a unique ring to a speaker. What we need is for the system to be physically compact so it can fit to replace and actual doorbell system in a home (which hopefully the Arduino can help to accomplish).

The reason the code is projected at around a thousand lines is since we may implement mobile application communications into it, locking/unlocking the door, etc. I'm making the assumption that 32 KB (from the Uno) is not enough based on the sizes of some of my C programs (that are in the thousand lines range) which are usually around 100 KB.

Basically, we need it to be scalable to a point where the program could be greater than our projected size or even less than it. We don't want to end up having to purchase multiple boards if one will suffice.

Comment: Without knowing what a "doorbell recognition system" is, it is hard to say which board would serve better. There isn't much price difference though so if in doubt, go with the Mega.

Comment: "A thousand lines of code" (in C?) is virtually *nothing* that would challenge a Mega32 or bigger. Libraries you may or may not link in can contribute a lot to flash usage, the same for constant data stored in the flash. You might have a look at the ATmega64 or ATmega128 which should come in pin-compatible versions to the Mega32 if more flash turns out to be required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

32 KB in a microcontroller is a lot of program memory. 1,000 lines of code is likely to assemble down to a few kilobytes, and all the Arduino libraries are likely to still be bigger than your program.

If I recall, I don't think any of the ATMegas support having external program memory. If you have something like a large lookup table, you could get an [I²C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) EEPROM and load it into there.

As for the PC/Raspberry Pi, some sort of [I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output) board for the computer is likely to cost much more than an Uno or Mega, ditto with the Raspberry Pi, especially if you need analog inputs or [PWM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation).

I would say, for now, stick with the Uno, but keep any pins you use as `#defines`, that way, if you do run out of program ROM, you could easily port it over to the Mega.

Comment: It is true that none of the 8-bit AVRs is able to execute program code from anything but the integrated flash memory.

Comment: It depends on your definition of "code". If you implement an interpreter in the flash memory then the to be interpreted code can be anywhere you want. If the interpreter happens to be a forth interpreter this is likely still very efficient.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying about the pi/pc, it probably will end up costing more in the long run.
I dont have much experience with the arduino, but if my c program was about 100-200kb in size, do you know (approximately) if that would assemble down to a size that would be usable by an uno? Would it just be a safer bet to get a mega?

Answer (score 0):

The Atmel microcontrollers do not support an external program bus that would allow adding ROM and expanding the amount of code.  Some devices support extending the data bus which would allow RAM to be added.  I would say this is one of the key distinctions between a microcontroller and a microprocessor, although there may be some fuzziness in the separation.  So when you run out of code or memory, you are stuck with finding efficiencies or cutting features.  My advice when picking a microcontroller is decide first:

Am I cost constrained or time constrained?

If cost constrained, then you pick the device you can afford and make your application fit.  If constrained by time, pick the largest device you can get away with.

You say you are time constrained and uncertain of the code scale.  If there is any way you can justify a $1000 PC+IO board the go that route.  Sounds a little expensive for a doorbell...

Comment: Actually, several of the AVR devices natively support external SRAM.

Comment: Yes, corrected mistake in answer.  Not ROM, yes RAM.  Although reading a comment above, you don't have an external program bus, but if you translate external data and execute does that mean external data is code?  Should have stopped at fuzzy.

Comment: I think the borderline is kind of blurred here. In every case one could accept data from any source imaginable and execute portions of code stored in the flash memory depending on the data received. This would be an interpreter for some language then (which I don't really consider as "executing code"). With the AVRs' capability of self-programming one can, on the other hand, transfer compiled, native AVR code as data to the µC, have the bootloader store it to the flash memory, and then execute it from there.

Comment: For this project we are constrained by both cost and time, however, if we need to spend a bit more to save time that would be better, just not too much. Since I don't have much experience with the arduino boards, im not sure how well a 100-200kb program would fit on a microcontroller with 32kb of storage

Comment: Ahh, so this is a real world project where it has to be cheap and fast :)  So this is why you buy in to a tool chain and microcontroller series.  Start small and see how low you can go.  Keep the ability to move up to the next larger processor as a mitigation strategy.  In case of Arduino and other AVR tool chains, you could move from one microcontroller to another with nearly zero code changes.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what your doorbell recognition scheme actually is. If it requires FFT and/or fancy floating point arithmetics, then you may easily exhaust the AVR's SRAM. If it is only some glorified finite state machine with a somewhat decent implementation I would be surprised if this exhausts an Uno.

The most important question though is: what are you building? A protoype? A one of? Or a pilot for a series? If it is not for a series then developer time is most expensive --> go for a bigger machine in the first place. If you are developing for a series compute hardware cost vs. developer time --> aim at the cheapest controller that will still fit your needs. That is: take the biggest of the Atmel family and once you have a running prototype shrink it down. IMHO a doorbell whatever thingy should fit into an ATiny.

Comment: It is a one off for a project we are working on, which is why it would be ok to get the mega, however if we can save money in the long run with an uno that would work out well too